# Скрипт для единоразового запуска в opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Как создать php-скрипт для единоразового запуска, допустим нужно сделать одну запись в базу данных, без создания модуля.
Также нужно создать новое подключение к бд mysql.
т.е. нужно использовать все возможности opencart mvc, но с новым подключением к бд
что то нужно типа такого:  `new \mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)` и выполнить скрипт

Comment: или скиньте пожалуйста ссылку, где можно посмотреть на реализацию, что-то не могу найти похожее

Comment: для единоразового запуска, или запуска по требованию? тут есть небольшая разница.

Comment: @Kirill, для единоразового запуска, нужно запустить всего один раз

Comment: @Kirill, подскажите пожалуйста, нет у кого больше спросить

Comment: Вы задали хороший, как для меня, вопрос. Ищу вариант.

Comment: похожий функционал есть в папке install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимально для взаимодействия с базой с использованием контроллера и модели `opencart` (проверено на версии **3**), из кастомного скрипта, не пренадлежащего ни к `admin`, ни к `catalog`, необходимо следующее:

```
require_once('config.php'); // будет использован конфиг catalog, но это не принципиально
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Config
$config = new Config();
$config->load('catalog');
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Log
$log = new Log('custom_log');
$registry->set('log', $log);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Event
$event = new Event($registry);
$registry->set('event', $event);

// Event Register
if ($config->has('action_event')) {
    foreach ($config->get('action_event') as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $priority => $action) {
            $event->register($key, new Action($action), $priority);
        }
    }
}

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Database
$registry->set('db', new DB(
    $config->get('db_engine'),
    $config->get('db_hostname'),
    $config->get('db_username'),
    $config->get('db_password'),
    $config->get('db_database'),
    $config->get('db_port'))
);

// данные сеты необходимы для использования стандартных методов моделей
$config->set('config_customer_group_id', 1);
$config->set('config_language_id', 1);
$config->set('config_store_id', 0);
```

Теперь минимально фреймворк собран, сдледующий шаг - контроллер. Он наследует system/engine/controller, что бы вся эта магия выполнялась.

```
// для примера, тащим все товары
class MyControllerCatalogProduct extends Controller
{
    public function getList() {

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts([]);

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Собственно, инициализация и использование

```
$product = new MyControllerCatalogProduct($registry); // $registry = new Registry();
$product->getList();
```